# How do I find all the tables which contains foreign key for given table primary key in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search all the tables from database which contains foreign key of given(specific) table's primary key in sql server. Please help.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: You are trying to find "exported keys".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this built-in stored procedure to search all foreign keys for the given table

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

If this doesn't suit your needs, you can try 10 other ways on this page - https://database.guide/11-ways-return-foreign-keys-sql-server-database-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT
  sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
  tables.name AS TableName
FROM
  sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
  sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE
  sys.columns.name = 'ForeignKeyColumnName'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good starting point:

```
select object_name(parent_object_id)
from sys.foreign_keys
where referenced_object_id = object_id('ParentTable');
```

This doesn't take into account that the FK is specifically referencing your table's PK. If the above doesn't narrow it down enough, start pulling in `sys.foreign_key_columns`. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.